# How do graphical DLC apply to in-progress game?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

I'm considering buying some of the [graphical DLC](http://www.ckiiwiki.com/Graphical_DLC), but I'm already in the middle of a game and don't want to start a new one.

So, when I load the existing game after buying the DLC, what will happen? Will existing dynasties have new shields (for Dynasty Shields DLC)? With existing characters change appearance or will only new no-parents characters have the new look (for portraits DLC)?

Answer (score 4):

For portraits DLC, old characters will stay looking the same, so you'll only see new faces on newly generated characters. Since your children use your portrait to determine how they look, this means that courtiers, peasant leaders and the like are the only people who will use the new portraits, to start with. If you start to have children with them, you may also start to look like them.

Not sure how the new shields will work, since I wasn't paying much attention when I bought that one.